# is there a way to autosave after every 2-5 mins in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I have come across ways to save on focus up `"save_on_focus_lost": true,`
or save on every change like this https://packagecontrol.io/packages/auto-save
but I am looking for time based saving where the code doesn't save too frequently like above methods but only after say every 5 mins.

Comment: u may ask on superuser.com site

Comment: @datdinhquoc From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the [help], software questions are allowed if they cover *"[...] software tools commonly used by programmers".* Sublime Text, like vim, emacs, VSCode, etc., is a programming editor, and there are [tens of thousands of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext2+or+sublimetext3+or+sublimetext+or+vim+or+vi+or+emacs+or+visual-studio-code) about them on this site that are perfectly on-topic.

Comment: @Ahmed that `save_on_focus_lost` seems the only option in sublime settings, just switch tab to have the previous file saved

Comment: @datdinhquoc Duplicated question to https://superuser.com/questions/1621404/is-there-a-way-to-autosave-after-every-2-5-mins-in-sublime-text . Please answer it there if you have a solution

Answer (score 0):

***There is no other way until now other than below:-***
**This is only for Sublime**. If you are using a different editor this will not work.
Open Sublime
Open 'Settings - User'
Mac - click Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Settings - User
Windows - click Preferences > Settings - User
Add this line
{ "save_on_focus_lost": true }
Save the file
Close the file